# How to eliminate last residual data point in InfluxDB aggregatewindow query

Tags: aggregate, influxdb

I have a query question with InfluxDB;

I am trying to aggregate the data per day and get the medians.
The dates are truncated to the start of the day (00:00:000)
But, the query returns one more last data which is not truncated to the start of the day;
How can I truncate the last data point’s time to the start of the day / or ignore the last value?

My query:

```
from(bucket: "metric")
  |> range(start: -30d, stop: 0d)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "metric")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["metric"] == "SOME_METRIC")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: median, createEmpty: true)
  |> yield(name: "median")
```

I added the query results and the text explains my situation

What I am trying to get is points as:

(Lets say today is 17.02.2022);

```
15.02.2022 00:00:00:000 - 16.02.2022 00:00:00:000 - 17.02.2022 00:00:00:000
```

But I got

```
15.02.2022 00:00:00:000 - 16.02.2022 00:00:00:000 - 17.02.2022 00:00:00:000 - 17.02.2022 05:30:27:437
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out that I must give exact dates instead of -d notation in the time range. In addition, the dates must be truncated suitable with the aggregate window.

```
from(bucket: "metric")
  |> range(start: 2022-01-16T00:00:00Z, stop: 2022-02-17T00:00:00Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "metric")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["metric"] == "SOME_METRIC")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: median, createEmpty: true)
  |> yield(name: "median")
```

Answer (score 1):

I will show on example data.
In my case I filter data with such query:

```
|> range(start: 2022-11-11T10:41:10.589Z, stop: 2022-11-11T17:47:05.518Z)
```

[image: filtred data for time range]

So from this we can see what is `_start` and `_stop`.
When we add `window` function

```
|> window(every: 1m)
```

[image: data with window function]

Clearly it behaves weird with `_start` and `_stop` in last row.
If we use solution with `window` and `median` function we will lose `_time` column. [You can read more about that here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/window-aggregate/)

---

## Solution #1 (round time range)

Round time range you filter:
Normally in grafana or other tool probably we will use such form of range:

```
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
```

but for test I will use:

```
start = date.time(t: 2022-11-11T10:41:10.589Z)
end = date.time(t: 2022-11-11T17:47:05.518Z)

start_rounded = date.truncate(t: start, unit:1m) //we can pass v.windowPeriod
end_rounded = date.truncate(t: end, unit:1m)


my_data = from(bucket: "gen")
  |> range(start: start_rounded, stop: end_rounded)
```

Thanks to this we will get rid of last row:
[(from range documentation)](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/range/#stop)

> Results exclude rows with _time values that match the specified stop
> time.

[image: without last row]

## Solution #2 (override _start, _stop)

```
  |> drop(columns: ["_start", "_stop"])
  |> duplicate(column: "_time", as: "_start")
  |> duplicate(column: "_time", as: "_stop")
```

but now we depend on `_time` rounding so not perfect solution if your data isn't aggregated. (not recommend)

---

Screens are taken from InfluxDB data explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too. I just end up NOT using `aggregateWindow`. Instead, try just using the window function with the aggregate function like so.

```
from(bucket: "metric")
  |> range(start: -30d, stop: 0d)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "metric")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["metric"] == "SOME_METRIC")
  |> window(every: 1d)
  |> median()
  |> group()
  |> yield(name: "median")
```

This seemed to resolve my issue...